# Decay and Invariant mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, neutrinos, invariants, pions

Consider the following decay :
\begin{equation}
    K^+\longrightarrow \pi^0 + e^+ + l^0
\end{equation}

where $l^0$ is a neutral lepton.

1. What kind of particle is $l^0$?
2. For $K^+$ , if it's at rest, calculate $l^0$ energy in function of $m_{k^+}$ and of the invariant mass $S_1$ of the system $\pi^+$ + $e^+$.

So, $l^0$ should be a neutrino $\nu_e$, for lepton number conservation.

What I don't understand is how can I separate invariant mass of the whole final system $\pi^0 + e^+ + \nu$ from the system   $\pi^0 + e^+$.

I wrote the relativistic invariant of the whole system, before and after, In laboratory system :
\begin{align}
S^2 &= E^2 -P^2 \\
&=m^2_{k^+}\\
&=(E_{\pi^0} + E_{e^+} + E_{\nu})^2 - (P_{\pi^0} + P_{e^+} + P_{\nu})^2
\end{align}

Ho can I relate this expression to the invariant mass of the second system, $$S_1=(E_{\pi^0} + E_{e^+} )^2 - (P_{\pi^0} + P_{e^+} )^2$$

Thanks in advance, I'm new to particle physics.

---

@Cosmas Zachos

thanks for your help teach.

So if I simply, for conservation of energy, write:

$m_{k^+}=E_\pi + E_{e^+} + E_\nu$

I should have obteined neutrino energy in function of Kaon mass.

$E_\nu =m_{k^+} -\sqrt{m^2_\pi + p^2_\pi} -\sqrt{m^2_{e^+}+p^2_\pi}$.

Since, in the first member, the invariant mass is :

$S=E^2-P^2 =m^2_{k^+}$, can i conclude that, neutrino energy in function of invariant mass is simply:

$E_\nu =\sqrt{S} -\sqrt{m^2_\pi + p^2_\pi} -\sqrt{m^2_{e^+}+p^2_\pi}$?

Is it correct in you opinion ?

Thanks a lot.

---

@Cosmas Zachos

Sorry Prof, last question. I forgot 3rd point of exercise,

" find Invariant mass of system $\pi^0 + e^+$ value that makes $l^0$ energy maximum."

So, from conservation of energy,

$ E_\nu=m_{k^+} -(E_\pi + E_e) $

So, $(E_\pi + E_e)$ must be minimum.

$(E_\pi + E_e)=(m_\pi + m_e)$.

Therefore $S_1 = (m_\pi + m_e)^2  $ in this specific case.
Is it correct?

Thanks again.

Comment: What laboratory system? You are *told* the K is at rest. Write the conservation of energy, balance momenta, and eliminate the relevant one in terms of the neutrino's energy and its mass. What is it you get?

Comment: Sorry. It?s not clear. Can you give me an imput? Should I simply make explicit those trinomial squares and then write simply every energy with Einstein notation?

Comment: You have simply failed to write down all equations you know. They are trivial, and allow solving for the neutrino energy.

Comment: I answered you . I don't know if tag worked.

Comment: Greetings! To respond to an answer, use a comment. Your two posts which should have been edits have been appended to your question. In the future you can do this yourself using the [edit] function, or you can ask a follow-up question.

Comment: 3rd point. Yes, but I shouldn't do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

You got conservation of energy,
$m_{k^+}=(E_\pi + E_{e^+}) + E_\nu$.

Now write down conservation of momentum,
$$
\vec P_\nu= - (\vec P _\pi + \vec P_e ), ~~\implies \\ 
  E_\nu^2 -m_\nu^2= (E_\pi + E_{e^+})^2-S_1= (m_K- E_\nu)^2-S_1.
$$
This is an equation for $E_\nu$. I suspect you might be expected to ignore the mass of the neutrino?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You literally saved my day. Exactly. I assumed neutrino had no mass. Now I's all clear.